# Changing Zone files with sed

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, scripting, sed, awk

I have this dns zone file I was unable to change the resource record type A to CNAME

```
@ IN SOA    ns1.domain.com. webdev.domain.com. (
        2006080101  ; serial
        8H      ; refresh
        2H      ; retry
        1W      ; expire
        4h)     ; minimum ttl

        NS  ns1.domain.com


domain.com      A   192.168.0.1

mail2           A   192.168.0.2

www         CNAME   domain.com

webmail                 CNAME     www
```

`sed -i 's/A/CNAME/g' dns-zone.file`

the above sed statement changes the A resource record  to CNAME but the CNAME also is changed to CNCNAMEME..

How can I change only the A resource record with out changing any other strings.?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `A` is a substring of `CNAME`, therefore the regex matches.

Try `sed -i 's/\sA\s/CNAME/g' dns-zone.file`, this will require whitespace around the `A`.